# Страница сообщений отмеченных пользователем не вся переведена

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

На странице сообщений отмеченных пользователем (список полезных тревог)  не переведено:

1. Сверху "Flags for"
2. Справа в "истории Ваших отметок":

   2.1 post flags, offensive flags.

   2.2 Clear all filters. Filter your flag history by selecting a category above.

   2.3 Ну и "Ваших" с маленькой надо, предполагаю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перевел больше десятка строк, относящихся к этой странице. Дополнительно отревьюил ждущие готовые переводы.

Спасибо andreycha и tutankhamun за участие.

<s>В ближайшее время переведенные строки должны появиться на сайте.</s>

**UPD:** Проверил 2 января: всё переведено, но явно нужно переделать строки про «отметки» (вероятно, это модераторская фича. Скриншот делал на своей учетной записи):

Там в сумме было 5 строк, поменял их, появятся при следующем обновлении боевой базы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD2:** 19 января новые строки появились.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]